# Create custom receiver for MQTT in spark streaming

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, mqtt

I have a requirement to do an analysis using spark on the data coming from IoT device via MQTT broker. The connectivity from my spark job is to MQTT broker where I can subscribe to a specific topic. I have used the MQTTUtils library in spark to connect to the broker, but I have doubts about how the library works internally. What I noticed is, "MQTTutils.createStream" connects to the MQTT broker for a topic. In that case, if I have to subscribe 100 topics in an MQTT broker, it may establish 100 connections to broker. That is not desirable in a real scenario. Please let me know if it is not working the way I think.

So I have decided to create a custom receiver for MQTT broker so that I can manage the connection in my MQTT client. I have gone through the document on how to implement a custom receiver, but I did not succeed in implementing it in the proper way.

If somebody has hands-on on such a custom receiver, please help me to make it works.

Appreciate your support since it is critical for my solution

Comment: This question is far too vague, you need to explain what you actually did and how it didn't work (show code/errors) and somebody might be able to help you fix it. Just asking for advice or for somebody to supply working code is off topic.

Comment: Presently my code works well with the MQTTUtils library, but I have faced a limitation in it. "MQTTutils.createStream" connects to MQTTbroker each time for a topic and no authentication params in it. So I am thinking of a custom receiver to stream data from MQTT client in such a way that it only makes 1 connection to broker with authentication and able to subscribe to various topics and stream all subscribed topics to spark streaming context.